# How to send LoRaWAN device data to FIWARE LoRaWAN IoT Agent from postman or MQTT Publisher client

Tags: mqtt, iot, fiware, lorawan

I have created an application in Things Network for LoRaWAN. Also registered a device within that application.

1. Already register a service in LoRaWAN IoT Agent and provisioned a device with provider as TTN in LoRaWAN IoT Agent.
2. Created a HTTP integration in Things Network Stack for my IoT Agent.
3. I also received data sent from Things Network Uplink client in my registered IoT agent.

Uplink payload from Things Network 
01 67 00 FF

Now i want to send uplink message from postman or MQTT publisher client.

I tried to create a payload for postman i.e. Url : http://MyMachineIP:4061/iot/json?=MyDeviceId&k=APIKEY

JSON PAYLOAD

```
{
  "app_id": "MyApplicationID",
  "dev_id": "MyDeviceId",
  "hardware_serial": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
  "payload_raw": "AWcA/w==",
  "metadata": {
    "gateways": [
      {
        "gtw_id": "TEST_1",
        "rssi": 0,
        "snr": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but got error Cannot POST /iot/json.

I also tried using MQTT Publisher Client:

1. Installed Eclipse Mosquitto providers a CLI to subscribe and to publish 
   messages.
2. Start Mosquitto Service.
3. MQTT command to publish uplink measure:

   ```
   mosquitto_pub -h eu.thethings.network -p 1883 -u applicationid-P ttn-account-v2.xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -t applicationid/devices/deviceid/up -m '{"port":1,"payload_raw":"AWcAuw=="}' -d
   ```
4. MQTT command to subscribe uplink measure:

   ```
   mosquitto_sub -h eu.thethings.network -p 1883 -u applicationid -P ttn-account-v2.x2Q20IXXXXX
   ```

Comment: Hi. did you have any luck with MQTT? I've been trying with Mosquito but the only publish that worked was publishing to '+/devices/+/down' ! I'm not able to publish to '+/devices/+/up' . If you had any luck, please post it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you reading this IoT Agent LoRaWAN guide https://fiware-lorawan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users_manual/index.html
Device provisioning, config and read this part:
In this case, the IoTA will subscribe to any observation coming from the LoRaWAN application server. Whenever a new update arrives, it will create the corresponding device internally and also in the Context Broker using the pre-provisioned configuration. Finally, it will forward appropriate context update requests to the Context Broker to update the attributes' values.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have gone through the IoT Agent LoRaWAN guide https://fiware-lorawan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users_manual/index.html few times. I want to send uplink measurse directly to LoRaWAN IoT Agent for checking IoT Agent performance. So I don't want to include any application server . Like using only MQTT publisher i want to send uplink measure directly to LoRaWAN IoT Agent.

Comment: Hi! I am sorry, you can't use IoT Agent LoRaWAN without application server neither LoRaWAN itself.